# How can I compare two columns of two different data frame and add new resultant column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame

First DF1: ( 7 x 3)

| ID | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | qwe | 1 |
| 123 | asd | 4 |
| 123 | zxc | 7 |
| 234 | ewr | 2 |
| 234 | sdf | 5 |
| 345 | xcv | 8 |
| 345 | qwe | 3 |

Second DF2:( 6 x 3)

| ID | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | asd | 3 |
| 123 | qwe | 6 |
| 234 | ewr | 9 |
| 234 | sdf | 2 |
| 345 | qwe | 5 |
| 345 | xcv | 8 |

I want to compare 123 ID of DF1 & DF2 and in that id compare Qty of items for DF1 and DF2 and get a new column.
And repeat the same for other ID's

where new column is

```
DF1['Qty_new']= DF1['Qty'] - DF2['Qty']
```

Result required : (7 x 3)

| ID | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | qwe | -5 |
| 123 | asd | 1 |
| 123 | zxc | 7 |
| 234 | ewr | -7 |
| 234 | sdf | 3 |
| 345 | xcv | 0 |
| 345 | qwe | -2 |

I've tried using

```
if (DF1['ID'] == DF2['ID']):
 while (DF1['Item'] == DF2['Item']):
  DF1['Qty_new']= DF1['Qty'] - DF2['Qty']
```

Getting error as: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Also tried

```
while (DF1['ID'] == DF2['ID']) & (DF1['Item'] == DF2['Item']):
 DF1['Qty_new']= DF1['Qty'] - DF2['Qty']
```

Error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'`

Please suggest.

Comment: merge them then calculate difference see [pandas-merging-101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Merge on ID and item, then qty_x - qty_y

Answer (score 1):

here you go, merge on id and item:

```
comb = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on=['ID', 'Item'], how='left').rename(columns={'Qty_x': 'DF1_Qty','Qty_y': 'DF2_Qty'})
comb = comb.fillna(0)
comb['Qty_new'] = comb['DF1_Qty'] - comb['DF2_Qty']
```